# Data sent in multipart volley request is received null after switching from localhost to server

Tags: php, android

My multipart volley request was working perfectly on localhost but after switching to server data received on server is null

```
private void getGamesByDate(String url, final String date, final View view) {
    // loading or check internet connection or something...
    // ... then
    String REQUEST_TAG = "Es";
    pd.setMessage("loading");
    pd.show();
    VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, GETGAMESBYDATE, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

            try {

                String resultResponse = new String(response.data);


            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            String errorMessage = "Unknown error";

            }
            Log.i("Error", errorMessage);
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("date",date);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            // file name could found file base or direct access from real path
            // for now just get bitmap data from ImageView
            //  Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.image_1 );



            return params;
        }
    };
    multipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000,1,1f));
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest,REQUEST_TAG);
}
```

this is my multipart request im sending date to server, im using multipart because the data received on server should be of format form-data

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct url both on the localhost and the server.

Comment: the request is working fine on postman and im using the same url on the app where im facing problem @Accountantم